# Count all Vowels in a String

Tags: java, methods

I am working on a program that counts the number of vowels in a string but I am getting an error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vowels = 0;
        
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String: ");
        String string = input.nextLine(); 

        string=string.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Vowels: "+ vowels);
    }
    public static void countVowels(String string)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<string.length();i++)
        {
            if (string.charAt(i) = "a" || string.charAt(i) = "e" || string.charAt(i) = "i" || string.charAt(i) = "o" || string.charAt(v) = "u")
            {
                vowels++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oh and I want to ask what it means to have methods without return value/with return value. Not sure if the code above has return value.

Comment: `char` primitives are written inside single-quotes, like `'a'`. Also, you compare with `==` , not just `=` which is for assigning a value.

Comment: You need to use '==' for comparison '=' is an assignment. Also, string.charAt(v) = "u" ? Should v be i?

Comment: You cannot reference local variables of one function (`vowels` in `main`) in another function (`countVowels`)

Comment: you are not even calling your function `countVowels()`

Comment: @sittsering yah, that is the only problem, callong the method class

Comment: You should have tried to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

My code above has many problems.

First, the main class not even calling the method class `(countVowels)`

Second, I used double quote `" "` and calling it `char`. String uses `" "` and char uses `' '`

Third, I used single `=` instead of `==`

Below is the refined code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String: ");
        String string = input.nextLine(); 

        string=string.toLowerCase();
        countVowels(string);
        
    }
    public static void countVowels(String string) //method class, dito yung parang procedure nung pagbibilang ng vowels
    {
        int v;
        int vowels = 0;
        for (v=0;v<string.length();v++)
        {
            if (string.charAt(v) == 'a' || string.charAt(v) == 'e' || string.charAt(v) == 'i' || string.charAt(v) == 'o' || string.charAt(v) == 'u')
            {
                vowels++; 
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println("Vowels: "+ vowels);
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of wrong things in your code.

In Java you represent a char with single quotes example 'a' 'b', etc.

String is double quotes and is an Object "a", "b".

You can't compare a Char with a String.

You need to comapre char with char.

```
string.charAt(i) == 'a'
```

and missing the double equals.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues have been answered by others, remaining few left.

Which are, you are not calling your function `countVowels()` and you have declare your variable `vowels` in `main` method, not in your function `countVowels()` .
Methods with return value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String: ");
        String string = input.nextLine(); 
        string=string.toLowerCase();
        int vowels = countVowels(string); // calling function which returns a value.
        System.out.println("Vowels: "+ vowels);
    }
    public static int countVowels(String string)
    {
        int i,vowels=0;
        for (i=0;i<string.length();i++)
        {
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'a' || string.charAt(i) == 'e' || string.charAt(i) == 'i' || string.charAt(i) == 'o' || string.charAt(i) == 'u')
            {
                vowels++; 
            }
        }
        return vowels;
    }
}
```

Methods without return value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        .... // same code as above
        countVowels(string);  // calling funtion, this doesnt return value      
    }
    public static void countVowels(String string)
    {
        int i,vowels=0;
        for (i=0;i<string.length();i++)
        {
            .... // same code as above
        }
        System.out.println("Vowels: "+ vowels);
    }
}
```

Comment: so for the the variable to have return value, the void must replace with int or any?
also, i already getting the idea because of the comparison

Comment: yes, it depends on the type of value you are returning. since `vowels` is int type, we use `int` as return type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix following issues,

1. The scope of variable `vowels` is set to method level so it is not available outside `main` method
2. The method `countVowels` is never invoked
3. Assignment operator `=` is used in place of comparison `==`
4. String literal is used `" "` in place of char `' '`

Comment: yah, my fault. I already answer my question, May I ask if it is now correct

Comment: It looks proper.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an alternative method, try this.

- stream the characters to be processed one at a time.
- filter those that are contained in the string of vowels.
- and count those that are passed through.

```
String str = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
long count = str.chars().filter(ch->"aeiou".contains((char)ch+"")).count(); 
System.out.println(count);
```

Prints

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a different approach ( it is definitely not the most starightforward solution one like using switch statements etc )

I have used linkedHasMap and then, stored the key and values ( based on each key as per the input string, we will store the count . If the key appears only once, their count will remain 1 else it will get incremented).

Once the linked has map is populated, I have iterated over the linkedhashmap and summed up the getValue for any vowel keys .

Hope, this gives a different food of thought on these kind of problems

```
 import java.util.*;
 class Main {
 public static int  countVowelConsonants(String inpStr) {
    Map<Character,Integer> inpCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int totalVowel =0;
    for ( char c : inpStr.toCharArray())
    {
        inpCount.put(c,inpCount.containsKey(c)?inpCount.get(c)+1:1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> iterator : inpCount.entrySet())
    {
        if (iterator.getKey()=='a'||iterator.getKey()=='e'||iterator.getKey()=='i'||iterator.getKey()=='o'||iterator.getKey()=='u')
        {
            totalVowel = totalVowel + iterator.getValue();

    }
    }
    return totalVowel;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    
    String inpstr = "StackOverFlow";              
    System.out.println(countVowelConsonants(inpstr.toLowerCase()));

}
}
```

Comment: It would do the work, but this much is not required for the solution.

Comment: I agree and if you see the start of my answer, I have stated that it is not the most straighforward solution. However my purpose was to show that, if you are given  different or complex lookup requirement, this map concept would be faster and more elegant  than using switch or loop type solution.